# fluent validation, use multiple parameters for validation

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have the following xml.

```
  <AttributeSet>
    <KeyName>accountType</KeyName>
    <KeyValue><val>administrator</val><val>developer</val></KeyValue>
    <!-- valid values are String, Binary and Email, Datetime -->
    <AttributeType>String</AttributeType>
    <Desc>Type of Account for the owning user</Desc>
    <Mandatory>True</Mandatory>
    <PrimaryKey>False</PrimaryKey>
    <LocalUnique>False</LocalUnique>
    <GlobalUnique>False</GlobalUnique>

    <CaseSensitive>True</CaseSensitive>
    <ValidSet Lookup="False">
      <TableLookup>Lookup</TableLookup>
      <ColumnLookup>AccountType</ColumnLookup>
    </ValidSet>

    <Size>
      <Min>1</Min>
      <Max>8</Max>
    </Size>
    <Resusable>False</Resusable>
  </AttributeSet>
```

I pass it to fluentvalidation which requires that the KeyValue must be checked for rules
like

```
 1) <Mandatory>True</Mandatory> if this is true the keyvalue must exist.
 2)  <Size>
      <Min>1</Min>
      <Max>8</Max>
    </Size>

   keyvalue size must be between these values.
```

my code:

```
  public class RecordValidator : AbstractValidator<Entity.EigenData.Record>
{
    public RecordValidator()
    {
        //first match 
        RuleFor(rec => rec.KeyName).NotNull();
       
    }

}
```

I really donot know how to check the min max and mandatory values using fluent rules.

any body can point?

Comment: You can use the `.Must((model, value) => { return [your logic] TRUE|FALSE; } )` to define custom validation rules

Comment: Did you mean you want to validate the `KeyValue` by Min and Max in `Size` xml node?